# How is the data parameter constructed in the swap function of 1inch AggregationRouterV5

Tags: delegatecall, calldata, encodefunctioncall

The swap function in AggregationRouterV5 is like this

```
function swap(
    IAggregationExecutor executor,
    SwapDescription calldata desc,
    bytes calldata permit,
    bytes calldata data
)
    external
    payable
    returns (
        uint256 returnAmount,
        uint256 spentAmount
    )
{
```

and i want to know how is data constructed, it's doc just says "see tests for usage example". It confused me, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the technique used in this [example](https://github.com/vishesh0123/FlashArbitrage---ETHernals/blob/9fe6247757ff23089e04902b23e7f25a55473ac7/contracts/FlashLoan.sol#L79). It's simply encoding the data again.

Comment: I still can't understand what the data means, but i've got answer. The data was constructed off-chain by 1inch's sever